# Is it possible to define a constant with variable name?

Tags: php, constants

I want to be able to generate some constants from an array. So something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    define($key,$value);
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I see no need to use constants for this type of thing, why not just use the variables?

Comment: Your code works fine http://codepad.viper-7.com/eeXE6J

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113663/dynamic-constants-in-php/12117642

Comment: It works fine. I just had something else in my code causing it not to work.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already doing this in your code. Or d you mean like this?

```
$array = array("sparkles" => "pretty");

foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}

echo $sparkles; //pretty
```

Comment: Those are variables, not constants

Comment: It works as I wrote it. I haven't needed to do this before and there was another bug in another part of the code preventing it from working. I feel pretty stupid assuming it couldn't work as I wrote it, but appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, if you have **many** constants to define, and APC installed:

```
$constants = array(
    'ONE'   => 1,
    'TWO'   => 2,
    'THREE' => 3,
);
apc_define_constants('numbers', $constants);
```

(straight example from [`apc_define_constants`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-define-constants.php))

---

Edit: [an interesting read about performance](http://shwup.blogspot.ro/2010/04/about-constants.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP 5.3 or higher, you could do:

```
array_walk($array, function ($value, $key) { 
    define($key, $value);
});
```

or

```
array_walk(array_flip($array), 'define');
```

---

But honestly, I would just use your current method.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can try to use `extract` function. It produces the same result (almost) as in njk's answer

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Oh, downvoting... Ok, it doesnt create any constants. To create constant in runtime you can try to use `eval` construction - but its a bad idea. Also you can look at my answer to the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113663/dynamic-constants-in-php/12117642#12117642

Comment: What does eval have to do with creating a constant?