# How do I call a static method of a class stored as a variable?

Tags: php

Why, in a class instance context, don't calls of the form `$this->className::staticMethod` work, but calls of the form `$className::staticMethod` do work?

In the example below `callDoSomething2` works, but `callDoSomething` does not work (I get a parser error). I'm using PHP version 5.3.15.

```
<?php
class A {
    private $className;

    public function __construct($className) {
        $this->className = $className;
    }

    public function callDoSomething() {
        $this->className::doSomething();
    }

    public function callDoSomething2() {
        $className = $this->className;
        $className::doSomething();
    }
}

class B {
    public static function doSomething() {
        echo "hello\n";
    }
}

$a = new A('B');
$a->doSomething();
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108795/dynamic-static-method-call-in-php

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

callDoSomething2 is one way to do it, the other would be to use something along the lines of

```
call_user_func("{$this->className}::doSomething");
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for why `callDoSomething` doesn't work? PHP parser just can't handle that?

Comment: Yes, it's a parse error -- The PHP parser just can't handle that.