# Call base Class function

Tags: php, class, function, object, call

say I have :

File BaseFoo.php :

```
require('MyClass1.php')
class BaseFoo(){

  function check(){
     //do somme stuff
  }

  function f1($o){
     $c = new MyClass1();
     return $c->f1($o);
  } 

}
```

File MyClass1.php :

```
MyClass1(){
   function f1(){
       ???->check() // how to call check() (in initiator BaseFoo class) ?
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Now question is : in MyClass1, function f1, I want to call check() function which is in initiator Class.

Thank for help !

Comment: you can make function check 'static' so u can call BaseFoo::check()

Comment: Yes I think that best solution, I ask myself if I could use something like parent (but not parent because there is no extends)

Comment: i add my post to new answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can make function check '`static`' so u can call `BaseFoo::check()`

Comment: Right, no other way ? Because BaseClass name is made by a define define ('__SERVICE_NAME__','BaseFoo'); So __SERVICE_NAME__::check() is working ?

Comment: you can use call_user_func http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108795/dynamic-static-method-call-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Because `BaseFoo` doesn't extend `MyClass1`, it isn't called a base class. This means that you indeed can't use `parent`. **You need to have an object on which you can call the method.**
Depending on what you want, you may need to create an object (or pass one) of class `BaseFoo` in `MyClass1` (local or as a member) or you may make `BaseFoo::check()` static:

```
class BaseFoo(){

  static function check(){
     // Note: you can only access static members here
     // Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning. 
  }

  function f1($o){
     $c = new MyClass1();
     return $c->f1($o);
  } 

}
```

Most likely, however, that's not what you actually want to do. You should ask the question "Who owns what?". Here, `BaseFoo` owns the `MyClass1` object. So you probably want this:

```
class BaseFoo(){

  function check(){
     //do somme stuff
  }

  function f1($o){
     $c = new MyClass1();
     check();
     return $c->f1($o);
  } 

}
```

And:

```
MyClass1(){
   function f1(){
       // Don't check here, the creator should check
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

You may need to check for different things both in `MyClass1` and in `BaseFoo` though, and you would have 2 separate `check` methods for that.

Answer (score -1):

If you google it you will find your answer, but [Check this page](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

So you can use something like that:

```
class BaseFoo(){

  public static function check(){
     //do somme stuff
  }

  function f1($o){
     $c = new MyClass1();
     return $c->f1($o);
  } 

}

class MyClass1(){
   function f1(){
       BaseFoo::check() // call static function check from BaseFoo
       // do other stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: BaseFoo doesn't extend MyClass1

Comment: if you google it you will find this usefull page, see example #2 http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php