# Calling different functions depending on the value of a given parameter

Tags: php

The problem is actually quite easy, but somewhat difficult to explain, but I'll do my best.

Assume the following function and class:

somethingsomething.php

```
function do_something($a, $b, $whatToDo) {
    $value = someRandomClass::doThis();
    return $a + $b * $value;
}
```

someRandomClass.class.php

```
class someRandomClass {
    public static doThis() {
        return $this->valueThis;
    }
    public static doThat() {
        return $this->valueThat;
    }
    public static doSomethingElse() {
        return $this->valueSomethingElse;
    }
}
```

So, we have a function which does ... something. It gets 3 parameters:

`$a` = An integer

`$b` = Also an integer

`$whatToDo`. = A string, either `this`, `that` or `somethingElse`

As you can see, the calculation in `do_something()` requires a value which is received through one of the 3 functions in the class. But the function which is called should be defined by the value in `$whatToDo`. Of course, i could create an if- or switch-statement which would look like this:

```
function do_something($a, $b, $whatToDo) {
    if($whatToDo === "this") {
        $value = someRandomClass::doThis();
    } elseif ($whatToDo === "that") { 
        $value = someRandomClass::doThat();
    } elseif ($whatToDo === "somethingElse") {
        $value = someRandomClass::doSomethingElse();
    }
    return $a + $b * $value;
}
```

But this looks horrible and if I got more (the actual code can have up to 41 different "`$whatToDo`'s") it's really difficult to read.

I wonder if there is a way to use a variable to "create" a function name and call that function, so something like:

```
function do_something($a, $b, $whatToDo) {
    $value = someRandomClass:: "do" . $whatToDo ."()";
    return $a + $b * $value;
}
```

so that if `$whatToDo` contains "this", it will call `doThis()`.

Is that possible by any means necessary?

Comment: This is supposed to work like this: someRandomClass::{"do" . $whatToDo}(); but please try to search the net better next time. Src: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108795/dynamic-static-method-call-in-php -> call_user_func('myClassName_' . $language . '::myFunctionName');

Comment: @dryman I searched for at least 20 minutes, but it's difficult to find something if you don't know how to describe what you're looking for. Google doesn't accept SO postsa search argument. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can made like this with a variable function:

```
 $fn = "do".$whatToDo."()"; // create a string with the function name
 $value = someRandomClass::$fn; // call it
```

More info:

http://php.net/manual/es/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: That's it, so simple, yet i was too stupid to find it. Tyvm.

Comment: It's so simple, but note that this only works with PHP 5.4 or later.

Comment: if you call `someRandomClass::$fn` then `return $this->valueThis` will not work as you called it as statically?

Comment: It works perfectly. Static functions are special because don't need instance, but it works without problems. See the #3rd example in the docs:  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables' value for calling function like

```
function a(){ echo "Testing"; }
$b="a";
$b();
```

This is gonna echo `Testing`