# Why can't I directly use function return values as dynamic class names in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error, late-static-binding

As of PHP 5.3, it is possible to use a variable as a class name, not only for object instantiation but [even for static methods as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108795/dynamic-static-method-call-in-php):

```
$className = 'My\Name\Spaced\Thing';
$thing = $className::foo('hello world');
```

However, if I try to use the return value of a function or method instead of an actual variable, I get an error:

```
function getClassName() 
{
    return 'My\Name\Spaced\Thing';
}

// Raises "syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)"
$thing = getClassName()::foo('hello world');
```

This, on the other hand, works just fine:

```
$className = getClassName();
$thing = $className::foo('hello world');
```

What gives?  Did I just find a bug in PHP's (5.6) syntax processor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'd call it a "bug," but it's certainly an idiosyncrasy of PHP prior to PHP 7. This, and a whole class of similar issues, was addressed by the [Uniform Variable Syntax RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is explicitly addressed in the RFC: "Static property fetches and method calls can now be applied to any dereferencable expression. E.g. $foo['bar']::$baz, $foo::$bar::$baz and $foo->bar()::baz() are all valid now."

Is there any workaround for PHP <7, other than just assigning to a string variable first?