# Call static function by method name?

Tags: php, methods

I have a couple of methods whose returns are being cached, and the cache key is the name of the method itself.

For instance, if this is my class

```
class tester {
  static function test() {
    $data = build_data();
    cache(__METHOD__, $data);
  }
}
```

The cache key value is `tester::test`.

I am implementing functionality to warm the cache. If I have all the cache keys, I could just call them one by one.

```
foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
  $key();
}
```

But apparently, I can't call a string like `'tester::test'` in this manner
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function tester::test() ...`

Do I have to do string parsing, to pull apart the class name and method, and then call them like `$class::$method()`? Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Should be the same use case as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108795/dynamic-static-method-call-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Lihs for linking the question in their comment; it turns out that `call_user_func()` does what I'm looking for.